# MVC Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values) redirects to the Area controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use RedirectToRoute method to force culture in the url. All was working until I create an Admin area in my project. Now the method redirects to the Area controller.

Example with the main HomeController : /Home/Contact

```
public ActionResult Contact()
    {
       Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);
       return View();
    }
```

The method redirects to /Admin/Home/Contact, the values of RouteData.Values before the redirection are :

```
[0] "Controller"  Home
[1] " Action"     Contact
```

My Main Route :

```
routes.MapRoute("Default_culture", "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",  id = UrlParameter.Optional , new { culture = "([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-zA-Z]{2})?" }, new[] { "Project.Controllers" });

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "Project.Controllers" });
```

Route in RegisterArea method :

```
context.MapRoute(null, "{culture}/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { culture = "([a-z]{2,3})(-[a-zA-Z]{2})?" }, new[] { "Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });

context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "Project.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

I don't understand this behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem in my site.

Change `Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);`

To `Response.RedirectToRoute("Default", RouteData.Values);`